# Use of Grid Tkinter GUI and is there any other correct practice to achieve this

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am doing an UI in GUI Tk . I the one which is marked in the 
"**Blue**" : I am using columnspan but also it is not extending till the end of UI frame . 
"**Red**" : Here I don't know why this here UI is middle Aligned .

I might be doing some simple mistake , I tried much to find solution . 
And 
Is there any other way than giving row and column number like in the below code , if there any other way to achieve it

```
Code =tk.Label(self.page2,text="Code ").grid(row=1,rowspan=2,pady=(10,10),sticky="NW")
CodeTextbox= Entry(self.page2).grid(row=1,column= 2,rowspan=2,columnspan=100,pady=(10,10),sticky="NW" )
SerialNumber=tk.Label(self.page2,text=" Serial Number").grid(row=3,rowspan=2,pady=(10,10),sticky="NW" )
SerialNumberTextBox=Entry(self.page2).grid(row=3,column=2,rowspan=2,columnspan=100,pady=(10,10),sticky="NW" )
Model=tk.Label(self.page2,text="Model ").grid(row=5,rowspan=2,pady=(10,10),sticky="NW" )
ModelTextbox=Entry(self.page2).grid(row=5,column=2,rowspan=2,columnspan=100,pady=(10,10),sticky="NW" )
KCheckBox=Checkbutton(self.page2,text="").grid(row=7,column=1,rowspan=2,columnspan=2,pady=(10,10),sticky="W")
FCheckBox = Checkbutton(self.page2, text="F").grid(row=7, column=3,rowspan=2,columnspan=2, pady=(10, 10), sticky="W")
OW=tk.Label(self.page2,text="OW").grid(row=9,column=1,rowspan=2,columnspan=2,pady=(10,10),sticky="NW" )
OWSupported=Checkbutton(self.page2,text="Supported").grid(row=9,column=3,rowspan=2,columnspan=2,pady=(10,10),sticky="W")
OWNOTSupported=Checkbutton(self.page2,text="NOT Supported").grid(row=9,column=5,rowspan=2,columnspan=2,pady=(10,10),sticky="W")
```

[image]

Comment: What is self.page2? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry I missed other part of code . Page2 my second tab . I mean &quot;Add&quot; tab which Is there in the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your columns have any weight associated with them, so they will all be as small as possible. Even though you do `columnspan=100`, columns 6-100 all have a width of zero. As a rule of thumb you should always give at least one row and one column a non-zero width so that the full amount of the space in the GUI is used.

Also, you aren't requesting that the entry widgets "stick" to the right side. So even if the column they are in expands the full width of the GUI, the entry widgets will not expand because you haven't told them too.

Finally, I strongly encourage you to separate widget creation from widget layout, and to group all of your layout code together so that it's possible to see all of your layout options as a group. The way you're doing it now, the variables are useless because they are all being set to `None`, since that's what `.grid(...)` returns.